# How do I use .any() to print the value I am looking for?

Tags: python, any

If I have the following code

```
if "ERB-776-RAD" in my_data.any():
    print("I found it!")
```

Where the my_data is something as follows:

```
my_data = ['ERA-776-TRF','FDS-342-FHS','EBR-776-RAD'...]
```

How would I print the actual value I am looking for (ERB-776-RAD) instead of printing "I found it"?

Comment: How can you look for a value without knowing it? Are you trying to get the index of the value?

Comment: Did you mean: `print("I found ERB-776-RAD!")`?

Comment: `list` doesn't have an `any` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` statement to test if the list contains the string. Then you can print anything you want if it's True. You can use string formatting to insert the value dynamically (in the code below, I am using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)).

```py
my_data = ['ERA-776-TRF','FDS-342-FHS','EBR-776-RAD']
target = "ERB-776-RAD"
if target in my_data:
    print(f"I found {target}")
```

As @chepner commented, lists do not have an `any` method. (If you saw `.any()`, it might have been with a numpy array or pandas dataframe.)